# Linux Mint Xfce window snapping bug

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, window-manager

I am using Linux Mint 18 Xfce 64-bit.

As you can see in the image below, for some reason left or right-snapping some windows like the Terminal, Emacs, etc. leaves these "breaks" in the middle and the bottom of the desktop (in the image you can see red behind these breaks - it's my desktop background). This does not happen for Thunar, Google Chrome or the majority of other programs. Any idea how to get rid of these breaks?

[image]

A zoomed view:

[image]

Comment: Well, you can always change your background to match your window border and forget about it... lol... just kidding. Did you try to change the Window Theme, maybe you can find one that do not have this issue.

Comment: They all have this issue, to a varying degree. In fact, Xubuntu also has this issue - so I think it's not a Linux Mint, but rather an Xfce, bug.

Comment: I use exactly your same distribution... please give me a list of programs that make this happen and I'll test them here.

Comment: emacs 24.5.1 and the regular terminal are the two I use which do this

Answer (score 1):

It is because some programs cannot have "any" window width or height. It is the case of emacs and the terminal, that are drawn in the screen as a number of columns and rows, but each column and row has a specific size.

Here is an example (in my own PC) trying to put each one to use half of the screen automatically: [image] As you can see, there is a space in the middle, and both windows left a space at the bottom, but I can not increase their height because there is no space for an additional row. And the same thing happens if I try to increase the width of any of the windows, they will end up over the other one.

I hope my answer is clear.

Comment: I get it, thanks for identifying the issue. But is there a solution? No other DE does this (e.g. MATE, Cinnamon, Unity)